# How to turn user input into an array

Tags: java, arrays, windows

I'd like to turn user input into a string array, and then edit that array for key words to change them, however I don't know how to do this and immediately ran into problems of trying to solve how to code this without an array going out of bounds.

The only code I have is this:

```
import java.util.*;

class FilterTest{ 

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        //String[] inputMessage = new String (); I don't know how to do the length here.
        input.nextString();
        inputMessage=input.nextString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `List`?

Comment: Like Sybren already said, just use an ArrayList<String>, a Vextor<String> or anything else allowing you a dynamic length.

Comment: I have no idea what that is, I'm extremely green. I'm assuming its exactly the thing im talking about?

Comment: An ArrayList can be used to store any data type, but if you use an ArrayList<String>, it does the same as a String[] => it stores strings. The difference to an array is that it does not have a fixed size, but you can just add to it or remove entries.

Comment: @cnbr15 please see my post for an example with `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with an `ArrayList`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> inputMessage = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        inputMessage.add(sc.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this format even existed. So I'm assuming that this works like a normal array in every form, just more flexible?

Comment: An array has a fixed size and a List has a dynamic length as Phiwa already said, please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Im on a timer to accept it, but I will as soon as I can, I do not wish to waste anyone's time

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*
class FilterTest{ 
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        Vector<String> all=new Vector<String>();
        while(true){
            String in=scan.nextString();
            if(in.length()==0){
                break;
            }
            all.add(in);
        }

        String array[]=all.toArray(new String[all.size()]);
        // here you go
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this is possible it would make more sense to use an ArrayList<String> or a Vector<String> INSTEAD of the String[] and not as an addition. :)

Comment: I get the error "input cannot be resolved" compiling this, I'm assuming I need to do something or I broke it? Thank you for answering though, looking at this makes sense other than the Vector, which i don't know.

Comment: sorry, it should be the name of Scanner

Answer (score 0):

The code below stores all input made into an ArrayList of type string until the input is "quit".

```
import java.util.*;

class FilterTest{ 

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        ArrayList<String> full= new ArrayList<String>();

        // We use a do-while loop to be able to check the condition of the loop AFTER each round
        // since we want to check if the user typed 'quit' AFTER he typed it.
        do {
            // Read input
            String input = input.nextString();

            // Add it to the ArrayList
            full.add(input);
        }
        while(!input.equals("quit")); // Cancel as soon as the user types "quit"

        for(String inputString: full) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with each input
        }

    }
}
```